How to create a list from a dataframe using indexing
This is probably a very simple question. But I can not figure out how to fix it.
I have a dataset with lots of columns and I want to run a loop to create histograms for certain columns. I know I can create a list using the column name but is there a way to use indexing instead?
See below an example using iris dataset and error I get.
# Function to repeat histogram over multiple predictor variables 
library(datasets)
data(iris)

vars=iris[1:3]
hist <- function(data, var){
  p <- 
    data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x =  .data[[var]], group=1)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
    theme_classic()
  return(p)
} 
## prints out the plots as in the loop
lapply(vars, FUN = hist, data = iris)

Error in geom_histogram():
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in .data[[<dbl: 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, ...>]]:
! Must subset the data pronoun with a string, not a double vector.

You have vars as an actual subset of the data. The way you've written your hist function, it's expecting column names. Make vars = names(iris)[1:3] and it should work just fine.

If you want to pass in a vector, then you can make a data frame inside the function, data.frame(my_variable = var) |> ggplot(aes(x = my_variable)) + geom_histogram(), but this is pretty strictly worse. Especially with lapply, which doesn't make the names accessible inside its FUN argument. So you could make histograms that way, but getting them labeled won't work unless you lapply over the names or switch to purrr::imap() instead of lapply, but why go to all that bother?

Alternately, make a wrapper for you function that applies it to all columns of a data frame and returns the plot list: hist_all_cols = function(data) {lapply(names(data), \(col) ggplot(data, aes(x = .data[[col]])) + geom_histogram()}) and then call that on your indexed data subsets, hist_all_cols(iris[1:3])

Gregor Thomas’s comment worked perfectly:

You have vars as an actual subset of the data. The way you've written your hist function, it's expecting column names. Make vars = names(iris)[1:3] and it should work just fine.

